# Enemy health bar ain't draining pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Okay so I was trying to make a health bar for my enemy class and only a part of it is working, what I mean is that every time I hit my enemy, I want its health bar to turn green to red and ,ale is lose 50 percent of it health, but that's not really working, the part of it needing 2 hits to kill my enemy is working but the part of the health draining and turning from green to red is not working. My problem is in the second main loop.

https://gyazo.com/9ab3f871afb9d3bcdd0fea0a0eadec87

when I shot at the player, the heath did not go down at all.

this is were I drew my color red and green.

```
pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 80, 10))
pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,255,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 80 - (5 * (10 - self.health)), 10))
self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)
```

this is were I told it to take away health

```
if Enemy.health > -10:
    Enemy.health -= 5
else:
    del enemys[one]
```

[my full code](https://pastebin.com/nMFmSH6b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything immediately wrong with the code sections.  I *suspect* it's not working because of the "health units" being used.

It may help to change you code to express these units as a percentage.  That way no matter what kind of enemy it is, `0` health means destroyed, and removes potentially confusing comparisons, e.g.: `-8` health = "somehow OK".

I've created a simple function to draw a red/green health bar.  I reasoned that for some larger time the health is at 100%, so only draw the negative-health part when necessary.

```
def drawHealthBar( window, position, health_percent ):
    """ Draw a health bar at the given position, showing the
        health level as a green part and a red part of 100% """
    BAR_WIDTH = 64
    BAR_HEIGHT= 8

    # Start with full health
    bar = pygame.Surface( ( BAR_WIDTH, BAR_HEIGHT ) )
    bar.fill( GREEN )

    # Work out the relative bar size
    if ( health_percent < 100 ):
        health_lost = BAR_WIDTH - round( BAR_WIDTH * health_percent / 100 )
        pygame.draw.rect( bar, RED, ( BAR_WIDTH - health_lost, 0, BAR_WIDTH, BAR_HEIGHT ) )

    # Draw the resultant bar
    window.blit( bar, position )
```

[image: demo screen shot]

Obviously if your targets have RPG-style "hit points", the percentage can always be passed as:

```
health_percentage = round( current_hp / maximum_hp * 100 )
```

Reference Code:

```
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH    = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT   = 400

BLUE  = (   3,   5,  54 )
RED   = ( 200,   0,   0 )
GREEN = ( 0,   200,   0 )


def drawHealthBar( window, position, health_percent ):
    """ Draw a health bar at the given position, showing the
        health level as a green part and a red part of 100% """
    BAR_WIDTH = 64
    BAR_HEIGHT= 8

    # Start with full health
    bar = pygame.Surface( ( BAR_WIDTH, BAR_HEIGHT ) )
    bar.fill( GREEN )

    # Work out the relative bar size
    if ( health_percent < 100 ):
        health_lost = BAR_WIDTH - round( BAR_WIDTH * health_percent / 100 )
        pygame.draw.rect( bar, RED, ( BAR_WIDTH - health_lost, 0, BAR_WIDTH, BAR_HEIGHT ) )

    # Draw the resultant bar
    window.blit( bar, position )




### initialisation
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )
pygame.display.set_caption("Health Bar")
font = pygame.font.Font( None, 16 )

### Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP ):
            # On mouse-click
            pass
        elif ( event.type == pygame.KEYUP ):
            # on Key-released
            pass

    # Movement keys
    #keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    #if ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
    #    print("up")


    # Update the window
    window.fill( BLUE )

    x = WINDOW_WIDTH  // 2
    y = WINDOW_HEIGHT // 7 

    # Draw health bars from 100 - 0 %
    for health_remaining in range( 100, -10, -10 ):
        # The health as a number
        text = font.render( str( health_remaining ) + '%' , True, (200, 200, 200) )
        window.blit( text, ( x-50, y) )
        # The bar
        drawHealthBar( window, ( x, y ), health_remaining )
        y += 25

    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick( 3 )


pygame.quit()
```